# 3 * 2 figures in one page

Tags: floats

I have to place six figures in one page.
There are three lines and two columns. 
Each figure have a subcaption. 
For this 3 * 2 figure, it has a caption too.

Thanks in advance. I try this. But it does work. So I have not add caption yet.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{
        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth, height = 0.2\textheight, keepaspectratio=true]{1.eps}
     \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth, height = 0.2\textheight, keepaspectratio=true]{2.eps}
             \end{minipage}} 
    \subfloat[]{
        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth, height = 0.2\textheight, keepaspectratio=true]{3.eps}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth, height = 0.2\textheight, keepaspectratio=true]{4.eps}
         \end{minipage}} 
    \subfloat[]{
        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth, height = 0.2\textheight, keepaspectratio=true]{5.eps}
     \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth, height = 0.2\textheight, keepaspectratio=true]{6.eps}
     \label{fig mmmf d}
        \end{minipage}}  
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Do you know the packages `subfloat` and `subfigure` and `subfig`? You can find them [on ctan.org](http://www.ctan.org/topic/subfloat)

Comment: There's also the `floatrow` package, which cooperates well with `caption`.

Comment: @tohecz - The `subfigure` package has been deprecated for more than a decade and shouldn't be offered up anymore as a possibility. You could also mention the `subcaption` package, by the way.

Comment: @Vivian - Are the six subfigures of (roughly) equal size?

Comment: @Mico Tell that to CTAN administrators, not to me `:-/`

Comment: @Mico, Yes. They are same size.

Comment: @tohecz - I'd say the CTAN administrators have done their job w.r.t. the `subfigure` package rather well: the package is stored in the `tex-archive/obsolete` branch, and the package's header page says things like "sub­fig­ure -- Dep­re­cated" and "The [subfigure] pack­age is now con­sid­ered ob­so­lete: it was su­per­seded by `sub­fig`, but users may find the more re­cent `sub­cap­tion` pack­age more satis­fac­tory." Is this forceful enough? :-)

Comment: @Mico However, they don't list `subcaption` and `floatrow` in the same topic, which is rather strange.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses the `subfigure` environment that's provided by the `subcaption` package. Observe the use of `\hspace*{\fill}` to achieve horizontal separation and of `\medskip` to achieve a bit of vertical separation between the graphs.

The `figure` environment as well as the individcual `subfigure` environments can be given `\caption`s, and these environments can be cross-referenced using the usual `\label`-`\ref` mechanism.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % "demo" option just for this example
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t!] % "[t!]" placement specifier just for this example
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pic1.pdf}
\caption{First subfigure} \label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pic2.pdf}
\caption{Second subfigure} \label{fig:b}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pic3.pdf}
\caption{Third subfigure} \label{fig:c}
\end{subfigure}\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pic4.pdf}
\caption{Fourth subfigure} \label{fig:d}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pic5.pdf}
\caption{Fifth subfigure} \label{fig:e}
\end{subfigure}\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pic6.pdf}
\caption{Sixth subfigure} \label{fig:f}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{My complicated figure} \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

A cross-reference to Figure~\ref{fig:1}, and a cross-reference to Subfigure~\ref{fig:e}.
\end{document}
```