# Unknown reason for non caption text occurring in figures

Tags: graphics, subcaption

I have been trying to use the following code to place multiple images as one figure, the code is an adaptation from the answer to  [3 * 2 figures in one page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165140/3-2-figures-in-one-page). However when the code complies the text "As-cast.jpg"is displayed on top of each image. Does anyone have any idea where this text comes from? Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % "demo" option just for this example
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\center 
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{TE As-cast.JPG}
\caption{AgAuPd} 
\label{TE As-cast}
\end{subfigure}
%White space
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{T+S As-cast.jpg}
\caption{Ag$_2$AuPd} 
\label{T+S As-cast}
\end{subfigure}
%White space
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{T+G As-cast.jpg}
\caption{AgAu$_2$Pd} 
\label{T+G As-cast}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{As-cast microstructures} 
\label{As-Cast}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: I would guess its from the spaces in the file names. Try removing those

Comment: Removing the spaced from the file name worked. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try with `\usepackage{grffile}` or use an extra pair of braces like `{{T+G As-cast}.jpg}` in `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{{T+G As-cast}.JPG}`. This happens if you have spaces in file names.  In fact you don't have to use the `extension`.jpg`.

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % "demo" option just for this example
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{grffile}  This or extra braces.
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\center
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{{TE As-cast}}   %% extra braces here
\caption{AgAuPd}
\label{TE As-cast}
\end{subfigure}
%White space
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{{T+S As-cast}}  %% extra braces here
\caption{Ag$_2$AuPd}
\label{T+S As-cast}
\end{subfigure}
%White space
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{{T+G As-cast}}  %% extra braces here
\caption{AgAu$_2$Pd}
\label{T+G As-cast}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{As-cast microstructures}
\label{As-Cast}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```